# Framework for a single page wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin which do some functionality say, save a form which user inputs and save as a custom post type. Also a button is added to front end which, on clicking takes to a new page which will do some main `js` based functions. So to do that special functions i need a `js` framework. I have considered vue, react and angular. Since that special functions include drag, drop and resize i am concerned about smooth movements and performance. I have gone through all available resources mentioning pros and cons. But still i am confused since i am using script on such a small part.

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you trying to work within WordPress or are you trying to create a web app outside of Wordpress? And please edit title to be more specific tho you particular Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque Already mentioned about wordpress plugin. I have edited my question

Comment: Then your title is much too general. Should say "WordPress plugin for …".

Comment: @BasilBourque Sorry. It was detailed in my answer. Also wordpress tag was added. I thought that might make the question clear

Comment: Better. And please fix your broken Shift key. A Stack Exchange is meant to be more of a respectable Wikipedia-like repository of wisdom and less like a casual chat room.